# Vertical space between theorems from a distant figure

Tags: spacing, floats, vertical, newtheorem

I encounter a weird vertical space in the following situation :
In my .tex, I have two theorems seperated by a picture, but in the .pdf, the picture is put somewhere else (and that's ok with me), but there still remain a small gap between those two theorems.
Any ideas on how to remove this gap ?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
blablabla
\end{theo}
\begin{figure}
%% Edit my Manuel Kuehner: 'example-image-a' is available for normal TeX distributions
% \includegraphics[scale = 0.1]{cube.jpg}
\includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\begin{theo}
bliblibli
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}
blublublu
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image: I am trying to remove the gap between Theo 1 and Theo 2]

Comment: The default for floats like `figure` is _never_ to see if it hits here. Try `\begin{figure}[htbp]`, also always give your figure a caption and refer to your figure by reference, not by _on the figure below..._

Comment: I don't want to moove the picture between the firt two theorems, I wan't the cube to remain above, but the vertical spaces between all theorems to be the same.

Comment: +1: Nice MWE for the first question!

Comment: That gives it an interesting spin. Why is there an extra space if say we force it to be `[t]`

Comment: I've pinged the kernel maintainers

Comment: A workaround: add the figure inside the first theorem, (and probably don't include `t` as one of the placement options). It works with the MWE. (BTW you can reduce the MWE by using `\rule{3cm}{3cm}` instead of the image, then `graphicx` is also not necessary)

Comment: Thanks ! Maybe not the cleanest way, but it will do fine for me.

Comment: Without a caption, you really don't need the figure environment (which adds gaps) at all.  You might need \noindent instead.

Comment: I've added to the kernel bug tracker. Though since this is related to the `\addvspace` that lists insert, this may be difficult to solve (I ashed the kernel people on the chat).

Comment: Consider accepting the provided solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `\begin{theo} and`\end{theo}`emit`\addvspace{\topsep}`.

If you have `\end{theo}\begin{theo}`, the two `\addvspace` commands merge the vertical spaces leaving just one.

This doesn't happen if between `\end{theo}` and `\begin{theo}` there's material that makes it impossible for the second `\addvspace` to “see” the previous one: they should be essentially consecutive.

You can reproduce the issue with just a `trivlist`.

A workaround for the case:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theo}

\newlength{\fixmidfigure}
\newcommand{\premidfigure}{\setlength{\fixmidfigure}{\lastskip}\addvspace{-\lastskip}}
\newcommand{\postmidfigure}{\addvspace{\fixmidfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
blablabla
\end{theo}

\premidfigure
\begin{figure}
  \rule{3cm}{2cm}
\end{figure}
\postmidfigure

\begin{theo}
bliblibli
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}
blublublu
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Thanks for the explanation. I would have guessed, that this kind of behavior would have been discussed or found long ago.